# How to fix when someone edits css output of an existing sass file

Tags: css, sass

A person directly edited the css output file. Am I in trouble here? He made edits all throughout the file and if I'm understanding correctly, my changes will overwrite his when I recompile. Is there anyway to keep everything but still work in my scss files? Could I take the entire css file and try the reverse css to scss path to get everything together?

Comment: There is no such thing as reverse css to scss.

Comment: Here's a converter. [css2sass](http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Yeah that's what I was referring to by reverse sorry if that was confusing. But my changes will overwrite his when I recompile correct?

Comment: That does not reverse a CSS output to the original SASS. It just converts a CSS to an equivalent SASS. It is impossible to reconstruct the original SASS code.

Comment: How to fix it is to fire the person who edited the output CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to save the edited CSS file and then compare it to your compiled CSS file, allowing you to determine what the changes are and add them to your Sass file.

1. Save the edited CSS file as `FileA.css`.
2. Recompile your Sass file into `FileB.css`
3. Load files `FileA.css` and `FileB.css` into a diff viewer, something like [DiffChecker](https://www.diffchecker.com/) or a desktop app like [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/).
4. Determine the changes and add the appropriate Sass to your original `.sass` file.

Comment: This strategy would also work if you were using `.sass` files, or any pre-compiling CSS language for that matter.

Comment: True, but he only has an edited `.css` file and his original `.scss` file (and a compiled `.css` file from the original `.scss` file) to work with. So it's not possible to compare 2 `.scss` files in this case.

Comment: Ah this is a great idea. Thanks @BrettDeWoody